# ColdFusion 9, secret setting

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

I have a small CF9 app, no database involved. In the configuration I need to store a network password which one of the functions needs, but I don't want to have it stored in the Application.cfc (for example) in human readable form.

What's the best way of storing/reading the password?

Comment: If you don't have a database then I would suggest at a minimum encrypting the password, but if everything is in the code anyone with the code would be able to figure out the password.

Comment: This might give you some ideas.  http://niallodoherty.com/assets/content/enclosures/Documents/Sourceless%20Deployment%20of%20ColdFusion.pdf

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** On a web page that is not going into production, run:

```
 <cfoutput>#hash('My_pa55w0rd')#</cfoutput>
```

That will show a hash of the password.

**Step 2:** On a web page that is going into production, add the hash to a variable such as `application.pass_hash` . Verify against `pass_hash` as needed.

```
<cfif hash(form.password) EQ application.pass_hash>
    <p>Successful login!</p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like the user is entering the password, but if they are then this is the best solution.

Comment: If you have a hashed version of the password in the source code, how can it be used for authentication?

Comment: We can know that the password matches what is needed without having the original password in the code